# Double array sum results are inconsistent with C++ on WIN32 and WIN64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am now developing a program that requires consistent results on WIN32 and WIN64. One difficulty I have found is that summation of double array values on these platforms may lead to inconsistent results. Take my codes snippet for example:

```
            double sum=0;
            std::vector<double>::iterator itW = weighting.begin();
            for(std::vector<double>::iterator it = x_array.begin(); it<x_array.end(); it++,itW++)
                sum += (*it)*(*it)*(*itW);
```

In the above code snippet, the weighted square value array summation is calculated. the `x_array` value looks like:

```
    [size]  982 long
    [capacity]  982 long
    [0] 202.00000000000000  double
    [1] 202.00000000000000  double
    [2] 202.00000000000000  double
    [3] 202.00000000000000  double
    [4] 201.00000000000000  double
    [5] 201.00000000000000  double
    [6] 201.00000000000000  double
    [7] 201.00000000000000  double
```

while the `weighting` array looks like:

```
    [size]  982 long
    [capacity]  982 long
    [0] 3.8144169965399290e-015 double
    [1] 1.0367629020002889e-014 double
    [2] 2.8179334245287864e-014 double
    [3] 7.6591752750373270e-014 double
    [4] 2.0526158725409399e-013 double
    [5] 5.5790334162148110e-013 double
    [6] 1.5163876629635047e-012 double
    [7] 4.1215590100336753e-012 double
```

I check carefully and see on both platforms `x_array` and `weighing` have the same value. However, the summation is different, on WIN32 the sum is 575994.17931926867 while on WIN64 the sum is 575994.17931926856. Any ideas why the results are inconsistent?

**EDIT:**
   (1) I am using Visual Studio 2010 for compilation. 
   (2) /fp precise and strict are both used, but it does not change the results.

Comment: Which floating point model are you using? You should probably use /fp:strict.

Comment: @Henrik, Thanks for the comments. I am using /fp:precise

Comment: My guess is, the results are the same and there is an issue with the conversion to decimal representation. I've entered both here http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html and it seems to be the same binary value.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for the instruction. But in my program the sum of the double array will be used as a variable parameter for a function. I do find that the function return value (in integer) is different in both platforms. It clearly shows that the summation is not the same on both platforms.

Comment: Just curious, is a 15 digit equality not sufficient? Even if you add a billion values with errors shwing the same bias you should only have a 10E-6 error.

Comment: I'm asking because equality of floats is at best doubtful to begin with (as you are certainly aware). Any notion of equality would involve a tolerance. I'm asking for the size of that tolerance because I suspect that for all practical purposes 15 digits is good enough. For example it's smaller than an inch on the earth's circumference which indicates that SpaceX's first stage missed the platform not because of rounding errors ;-).

Comment: @PeterSchneider I am writing a iterative line estimation function now. The way how I calculate the line is based on the following procedure: 1) use least square method to obtain the initial line based on the point coordinates; 2) calculate the weighting for each point based  on its distance to the line; 3) use weighted least square method to re-calculate the line; 4) compare the line angle disparity for the two consecutive lines, and if the disparity is lower than a threshold; then stops; other wise go to step 2) and repeat 3) and 4). In step 3) I need get the weighted sum.

Comment: And a 1E-15 tolerance is unacceptable for the sum?

Comment: @PeterSchneider In my test I do find that 1e-15 tolerance is not fine. Most cases it will work, but only a very very few examples fail.

Comment: Have you tried to disable optimisations?

Comment: @n.m. I am using Debug version now, and optimization is disabled.

Comment: can you post your entire arrays somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that in 64-bit compilation, the MSVC compiler prefers to use SSE instructions, presumably to gain speed via SIMD. In 32-bit compilation it uses the older integrated x87 FPU instructions.

The x87 Floating-point unit uses extended-precision 80-bit floating point registers. Depending on your compiler optimisation settings, the compiler will store intermediate accumulation results (your variable sum) in 80-bit precision registers. This extra 16-bits of precision is used, because multiplying two double precision numbers results in a 128-bit precision number before truncation.

The SSE registers are 64-bit IEEE double-precision floating point registers. So you lose a little accumulated precision in the 16th decimal digit - which is about the place you would expect FP truncation errors to appear in any simple sum of products of positive numbers, with double precision.

For more details, see ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" Goldberg 1991 ACM.](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf)

Comment: I'd think that's the issue. Btw, there is a `/arch (x86)` option for x86 code generation which disables SSE. For x64 there are only AVX related options (cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620901.aspx). Perhaps the 64 bit compiler always generates SSE instructions?  I'm not a VS specialist but would assume that one can build x86 programs (and then with /arch (x86) enabled) with VS on a 64 bit machine. That may be your solution.